Unable to Connect to Localhost After Setting Up Airflow DAG in Docker
I recently installed Docker on my Windows machine and set up Airflow for managing my DAGs. Initially, everything worked fine, and I was able to connect to localhost to access Airflow's web interface. However, after shutting down my system and attempting to reconnect to localhost, I encountered the following error:
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
